# Dialog makes the app crash every second time (weird)

Tags: android

My class sends my `MainActivity` broadcast. My `MainActivity` then shows an `AlertDialog` with respective string inside. Here is the code-

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(keyReceiver, new IntentFilter("intentKey"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver keyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // get real-time status updates
        String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
        if (status.equals("update")) {// offer user update
            Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            Dialog.setMessage("Update app to the latest version?");
            Dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "update",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            NSOMUC.downloadUpdates();
                        }
                    });
            Dialog.show();
...
```

The problem is, this works perfectly fine, it shows the dialog, but on every second launch, it crashes with an exception. It works fine on the next launch. And then crashes on the next.

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@89b1ec1 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

And this is how I am sending broadcast

```
   // finally send broadcast to MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent( "intentKey" );
        intent.putExtra( "status", status_string );
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( context ).sendBroadcast( intent );
```

This is really driving me nuts.

Comment: Are you unregistering the Receiver anywhere?

Comment: Huh? I mean, are you calling `unregisterReceiver()` on `LocalBroadcastManager` anywhere? Anyway, since you're showing a `Dialog` from that Receiver, you should probably be registering it in `onResume()`, and unregistering it in `onPause()`.

Comment: @MikeM. no, I don't think I am using `unregisterReceiver()` anywhere

Comment: Then I would suspect that that's your problem, because the Receiver instance registered from the first launch is still there the second time around.

Comment: @MikeM. that solved my problem! :) please tell me if there is a way to tell if `LocalBroadcastManager ` is running ? so it does not start twice.

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` doesn't really "run", as it were. It keeps a static list of registered Receivers, and dispatches broadcasts when sent, so you just need to make sure to unregister your Receivers when appropriate. There's really no built-in way to determine if you've registered a given Receiver without sending a broadcast, but your app would've crashed by then anyway. It's up to you to keep track of them.